# Confusion regarding SEO friendly PHP links

Tags: php, html, seo

Is SEO affected by the type of titles PHP generates?

Eg: CamelCased link (not easy to read) `http://website.com/HelloWorld.php`
or
Link with hypen (easy readable) `http://website.com/hello-world.php`

What's your opinion on this? Which rules are to be followed to keep my webpages search engine friendly?

Comment: it's better to use htaccess, the second link is more seo friendly

Comment: @mgraph Can you please explain in detail, I am unaware of that.

Comment: helloWorls is considerated as one word but hello-world google considerate it as 2 words hello and world

Comment: @mgraph I need to know about htaccess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The - is a word separator. In Hello-World, google recognises the words, hello and world. HelloWorld will be understood as one word, and will not contribute to the term hello world. Also important, the underscore character (_), is not a word separator, so Hello_World will not be recognised as hello world.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this by .htaccess I suggest using this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [NC,L]
```

Which drops the .php and allows for more SEO-friendly URLs e.g. http://website.com/2012/02/04/name-of-the-article. 
Inside the index.php catch the URI with $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and include the file you want.